# Xpath getting sum of all children and grandchildren values

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<results>
    <bonuses>
        <bonus BID="b1">3</bonus>
        <bonus BID="b2">6</bonus>
    </bonuses>
    <question QID="q1">4</question>
    <question QID="q2">7</question>
    <question QID="q3">9</question>
</results>
```

Given the above code, what would be the proper way to find the sum of all the elements. I.e. (3 + 6 + 4 + 7 + 9)?

The closest I could get is only getting the sum of the bonuses:

```
sum(/results/*/*)
```

Comment: hr_117 and vtd_xml_authors have great starts. The most appropriate answer will depend on how uniform and consistent your source XML is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get sum of notes without children try:

```
 sum(/results//*[not(*)])
```

Comment: this one is more efficient than mine!

Answer (score 1):

How about `sum(/results/*/*)+ sum(/results/question)`?